# How handle a connection to PDO between multiple classes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i want know if there is a right way to handle a connection of PDO between multiple PDO classes, i explain my question with one example:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname='myDB';host=localhost; "user", "password");

$classa = new ClassA($db);

//Then Class A use the PDO and maybe pass the $db to other class etc

//set $db = null only in this class where i have created it
$db = null; //this is needed?
```

or doesn't pass the reference of the $db like the example above, but in every class create a database connection.

so what is the better choice? create a database connection in one class and the pass the reference between classes, or create in every class a database connection, also for the performance what is the best?

Comment: Why are you trying to get rid of a reference that other things might still be using? Until `$classa` goes out of scope, it either should manage the lifetime of its' input on its' own, or it should have a way to explicitly clear its' reference to `$db`. Anything else is just going to be fraught with peril and extremely fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you bother with simple research then you will find thet first option is the only acceptable one, and quite a mainstream approach. Opening multiple connections makes no sense and pretty likely will kill your database server.

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrap file, which is the one that "loads" all the others, the start point, you load the Database class.

In your "bootstrap" class, you can have an static array of "services" (Initialized classes) that you could get everywhere using another static method, like `App()::getService('DbConnection')`.

That would return the PDO object where you can make your queries, and no need to create new objects for every class.

There are many many more ways, this is just the first one I  thought on. And you can for sure look at some "micro framework" that has Services so you avoid crating it. If you want to experiment, its good to do then.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
class A {
    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname='myDB';host=localhost"; "user", "password");
    }
}

class B {
    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $classA = new A();
        $this->db = $classA->db;
    }
}
```

You might need to do the following then aswell but I don't know for sure:
In a file you include everywhere:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    include_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
});
```